# AppTrackingTransparency and SDK initialization (Facebook, Firebase...)

Tags: ios, apptrackingtransparency

I'm a bit lost about `AppTrackingTransparency` and how to initialize some SDKs (like FB or Firebase), especially after a user first install of the app.

I don't want to show the user the app tracking transparency popup IMMEDIATELY after he installs the app because it feels too aggressive. I prefer him to go through a few steps before.

However, I know that I need to initialize some SDKs in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunching` method, i.e.:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // FB
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
    }
    return true
}
```

What I'm afraid of is that initializing these SDKs before showing the `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` popup later in the app could lead to a rejection from Apple, or these SDKs to not work properly. Or can I let this code like this and call the `requestTrackingAuthorization` later without any issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firebase should always be the last initialization before the return true.  Otherwise your code is good.